# How to perform an SQL query with PYODBC using a column name variable?

Tags: python, sql, variables, pyodbc

I have written several functions to get particular items of data like this:

```
def get_short_desc(self, part_num):
    sql = 'SELECT impShortDescription FROM Parts '
    sql += 'WHERE impPartID LIKE ?'

    self.cursor.execute(sql, [part_num])
    item = self.cursor.fetchone().impShortDescription

    return item
```

I want to paramaterise the functions so I am not repeating myself (DRY):

```
def get_part_entry_item(self, var, part_num):
    sql = 'SELECT ? FROM Parts '
    sql += 'WHERE impPartID LIKE ?'

    self.cursor.execute(sql, [var, part_num])
    item = getattr(self.cursor.fetchone(), var)

    return item
```

The execute statement passes the value of `part_num` (a string) with single quotes which is correct. When the column name variable `var = 'impShortDescription'` the resulting SQL is effectively  `SELECT 'impShortDescription'...` so the item returned is

`('impShortDescription', )`

so `getattr(self.cursor.fetchone(), var)` causes the error

`AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'impShortDescription'`

How do I pass a column name without the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL substitution only works on values, not on table or field names.  Do this.  Yes, this means you must be careful not to pass user data as the field name.

```
def get_part_entry_item(self, var, part_num):
    sql = f'SELECT {var} FROM Parts '
    sql += 'WHERE impPartID LIKE ?'

    self.cursor.execute(sql, (part_num,))
    return self.cursor.fetchone()[var]
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Roberts.  User data issue noted.